# Mock only one method of an Angular service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have an angular service where one method listens for state changes and returns an observable, but other methods of the same service perform transformation logic:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.myService.stateListener().subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.data = this.myService.transformModel(res);
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.cd.detectChanges();
    }, (err) => {
        this.errMessage = 'Data could not be loaded';
        this.isLoading = false;
    });
}
```

In the tests I mock the state listener to return specific testable data like so:

```
const mockService = jasmine.createSpyObj('myService', ['stateListener']);
mockService.stateListener.and.returnValue(of({
    number: 107,
    mock: someMock
}));
```

The problem is since I have mocked the service, the method 'transformerModel' no longer exists (on the mocked service) so the data that is bound to the component is 'undefined'.

Is there a way to mock out just the returned observable (stateListener) without mocking the transformer method of the same service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let testData={}// stubbed response of Observable or Model
let dataStub=fixture.debugElement.injector.get(MyService);
spyOn(dataStub, 'stateListener').and.returnValue(
      Observable.of(testData)
    );
```

You can use the `stub` and `returnValue` and `Observable.of` to stub it and return the observable.